# Google Consent-Mode: "Region-based-Consent" always on granted, although everything is on denied?

Tags: javascript

I come from Germany and my English is only as good as Google Translator :-)

I've been reading here for years and am now asking my first question:

I integrated Google Consent Mode correctly according to Google instructions (it's not too difficult) and tested it in the tag assistant. It responds correctly to the user settings in the following columns and changes to **granted** or **denied** accordingly:

- On-page Default
- On-page Update
- Current State

The problem is the preceding **Region-based-Consent** column. This always stays on granted, no matter what I do. (see attached image) Although I didn't make any region-specific settings in the code.

[Tag assistant Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ueSGn.jpg)

**What does that mean now???**

According to the attached screenshot, will the user data continue to be processed for the processing purposes (ad_storage, analytics_storage, ad_user_data, ad_personalization) even though all other columns are set to denied??? Or is everything correct? Why doesn't the **Region-based-consent** column change? I stand on the hose. My question actually only revolves around this unfortunately unresponsive column...

Thanks in advance and greetings from Germany!

**Example-Code for information (nothing special):**

```
<head>

<!-- Google Consent Mode v2 Default -->
<script>
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}

gtag('consent', 'default', {
  'ad_storage': 'denied',
  'ad_user_data': 'denied',
  'ad_personalization': 'denied',
  'analytics_storage': 'denied',
  'wait_for_update': 1000
});
gtag('set', 'ads_data_redaction', true);


<!-- Here are the typical GOOGLE TAGS for analytics etc., I'll save those -->


<!-- Google Consent Mode v2 Update Function -->
function consent_granted_ad_storage(){
gtag('consent', 'update', {
'ad_storage': 'granted'
});
}

function consent_granted_ad_user_data(){
gtag('consent', 'update', {
'ad_user_data': 'granted'
});
}

function consent_granted_ad_personalization(){
gtag('consent', 'update', {
'ad_personalization': 'granted'
});
}

function consent_granted_analytics_storage(){
gtag('consent', 'update', {
'analytics_storage': 'granted'
});
}

function consent_denied_ad_storage(){
gtag('consent', 'update', {
'ad_storage': 'denied'
});
}

function consent_denied_ad_user_data(){
gtag('consent', 'update', {
'ad_user_data': 'denied'
});
}

function consent_denied_ad_personalization(){
gtag('consent', 'update', {
'ad_personalization': 'denied'
});
}

function consent_denied_analytics_storage(){
gtag('consent', 'update', {
'analytics_storage': 'denied'
});
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<!--  Example of calling the functions -->
<button onclick="consent_denied_analytics_storage()">No</button>
</body>
```

Ich hope sombody can help me and had the same problem.

Comment: Forgot to copy the "Hi Community" so I'll say it now: Hi Community!!!

Comment: Indeed, the Region-based Consent column doesn't seem to actually reflect region-based defaults. They consent states always show "Granted". I see two options: 1) This is a UI bug, where the column doesn't appropriately reflect region-based defaults, or 2) Google is planning to set opt-in regions (e.g. EU) to default to "denied" and opt-out regions to "granted".

Comment: FYI, I got word that this was an inadvertent update by Google and will be rolled back to wait for proper feature release.

Comment: Thank you very much! The Region-based Consent column is now removed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue.

[image]

I think ***Consent Mode*** is still working as it should, meaning that even though ***Region-based Consent*** is granted, the default/update dynamic is working as it should.

For example the Google Ads Remarketing Tag `tag-status` is `"Still running"` even though with `Update = Denied`, even though ***Region based Consent*** is all granted.

Probably some kind of update that one of the experts is gonna publish a LinkedIn thread about soon (hopefully).

I'm moving on assuming everything is working just fine.

Comment: Thank you very much! The Region-based Consent column is now removed. See the comments from Simo Ahava above.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same with the Simo Ahava's template. I tried to remove the Region from the template, but it still gets filled in (how? by what?), and always Granted.

The only wild guess that I ended up with would be: what if that is signaled by Chrome based on the location settings of the user.
Which now is Granted all over the world/any location, because the EU GDPR latest regulation did not reach the deadline for implementation. & what if after March that Region will be populated automatically according to the location:
if from US: it will show Region-based = Granted;
if from EU: it will show Region-based = Denied.

Can anyone confirm this logic?
If you see any explanation popping up in social media, pls share it here too.

Comment: This is a possibility, although Google can't collect location data from browser APIs unless the user gives permissions to do so, and it's the site that needs to query this permission, not Google Analytics.

GA geolocates the user when the browser loads the library, based on an IP reverse lookup. So the Google Analytics library has the user's (possible) region known when they evaluate things like region-based defaults for consent mode.